# Standard POSIX read shadowed by a read method with different signature

Tags: c++, shadows, unistd.h

I have a C++ File class with read function, that is supposed to read whole contents of a file (just like Python does) into a buffer. However, when I tried to call read function from unistd.h, I get:

> file.cpp:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘File::read(int&, char*&, int)’
>
> file.cpp:17: note: candidates are: char* File::read()

What am I doing wrong? These have completely different signatures, why can't I simply call it?

Comment: Are you going to show us code, or just let us guess all day?

Comment: Without the code you can only get guesses.

Comment: You really included <unistd.h> ? Try calling ::read(..whatever) instead of read(..whatever)  though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried being explicit about scope;

```
char* File::read()
{
   // Double-colon to get to global scope
   ::read(...);
   // ..
}
```

?

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what I needed. Too much Python, I must go back to C++ and get this all back again :-)

Answer (score 2):

The definition for the posix standard version of the read method is defined as `extern "C"`.  This is neccesary so that the read symbol is not mangled by the C++ compiler and links against the proper function in the library.  Mixing and matching C and C++ symbols will have unpredictable results.  If possible, rename the c++ function so as not to conflict with any symbols that are declared `extern "C"`.